# How to sovle this problem using Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Using Rouche’s Theorem, or otherwise, compute the number of zeros
of the polynomial
$
p(z)=z^{7}+3z^{4}+12z^{2}+1
$

which lie in the annulus 1 < |z| < 2.
The only thing I can do is:
$|z^{7}+3z^{4}| < |1+3|=4<13=12|z|^{2}+1$
which means there is two zeros

$|3z^{4}+12z^{2}+1| < 128=|z^{7}|$
which has 7 zeros
therefore, the result is 7-2=5.
However, someone in the comment says there is 4 zeros

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question